# How many real and imaginary numbers have absolute values equal to k, supposing k is a positive real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose k is a positive real-number constant. How many pure real numbers have absolute values equal to k ? How many pure imaginary numbers have absolute values 
equal to k? How many complex numbers have absolute values equal to k ?

Comment: 2,2 and infinity

Comment: More precisely, 2, 2, and continuum-many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real solutions we have  two solutions $$ |x|=k \implies x=\pm k$$

For pure imaginary  solutions we have two solutions $$ |iy|=k \implies iy=\pm ik$$

For complex solutions we have  infinitely many solutions $$ |x+iy|=k \implies x^2+y^2 = k^2 $$